# Can a spellcaster Dispel an effect caused by an Alchemist's bombs?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

I'm trying to build a bit of a foil for one of my more competent casters, and I came upon a conundrum.

The [Smoke Bomb discovery](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/smoke-bomb/) reads as follows:

> When the [alchemist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist) creates a bomb, he can choose to have it create a cloud of thick smoke when it detonates. The cloud functions as [Fog Cloud](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=fog%20cloud), filling an area equal to twice the bomb's splash radius for 1 round per level.

Because it uses the phrase "As Fog Cloud," does that mean a wizard could use a targeted Dispel Magic to clear the smoke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dispel magic would not affect the smoke bomb. The smoke bomb discovery is a SU special ability and under that description we have the answer.

[Supernatural Abilities](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities/) (Su)

Supernatural abilities are magical but not spell-like. Supernatural abilities are not subject to spell resistance and do not function in areas where magic is suppressed or negated (such as an antimagic field). **A supernatural ability’s effect cannot be dispelled and is not subject to counterspells.**